# How to get a variable value defined in a function form oute of the function

Tags: python

I use python 2.7

such as the code followed

```
def func_a(var_a):
    a = 1
    b = var_a
    return b
```

how to get the value of a in function func_a ??

Comment: return it? `return a`

Comment: Don't use python2. It's dead. If you need a value from a function, `return` it.

Comment: Which value? a or b?

Comment: Not return, but just know the value

Comment: Why do you need to know the value outside of the function? What is the actual problem you're asking about?

Comment: I writing a decorator and want to print or using the value of a

Answer (score 1):

Here you go;

```
def func_a(var_a):
    global a
    a = 1
    b = var_a
    return b
res = func_a(2)
print(res)
print(a)
```

`global` keyword is used to make a variable global. So you can  access it outside the function also.

You can also return the value.

Here i used `global` on `a` and returned `b`.

Answer (score 0):

try like this you will find the answer;

def square(x):

```
y = x * x
return y
```

toSquare = 10

result = square(toSquare)

print("The result of", toSquare, "squared is", result)'